# How to create separate section on wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, sections

I am working on wordpress project but I can't understand how the old developer create diff separate section on diff pages.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your wordpress is using ACF Pro Tabs.

You can check in Dashboard left column ACF > Field groups there shall be one associated to diff pages in wich tabs are generated.